# How to deal with for-loops in plotting multiple graph in the same plot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, indexing

The template program works but a drawback is that there are many lines of plot(). How do I replace the 6 lines of plot() with a for-loop that works? 
How would I deal with the index and labels?

```
    """
    # Import
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    # Experimental data
    y_data = []
    y_data.append([21.2, 32.5, 42.1, 54.5, 23.5])
    y_data.append([17.2, 27.6, 35.7, 45.8, 27.1])
    y_data.append([25.7, 34.1, 34.7, 50.3, 31.3])
    y_data.append([11.2, 32.5, 45.1, 54.5, 23.5])
    y_data.append([27.4, 25.6, 45.7, 37.8, 25.1])
    y_data.append([23.4, 22.1, 54.7, 45.3, 19.3])

    # For x-axis
    x_data = range(1, len(y_data[1])+1)

    # %% Repetitve use of plot 
    # The following code plots the data but is repetitive 
    #
    fig1 = plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x_data, y_data[0], label='Expt on 31-01-18')
    plt.plot(x_data, y_data[1], label='Expt on 02-02-18')
    plt.plot(x_data, y_data[2], label='Expt on 05-02-18')
    plt.plot(x_data, y_data[3], label='Expt on 07-02-18')
    plt.plot(x_data, y_data[4], label='Expt on 10-02-18')
    plt.plot(x_data, y_data[5], label='Expt on 17-02-18')
    plt.legend()
    plt.xlabel('input')
    plt.ylabel('output')
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: What template program? Please show the code you are trying to run.

Comment: Don't use picture in question, just copy the texted in to the question itself, makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Sorry, fixed it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The items you can compute in sequence, you code into loop sequences.
The items that change irregularly, you put into a list.
You already have this technique for the data; just extend it to the labels as well.

```
label_list = [
    'Expt on 31-01-18',
    'Expt on 02-02-18',
    'Expt on 05-02-18',
    'Expt on 07-02-18',
    'Expt on 10-02-18',
    'Expt on 17-02-18'
]
for plot_num in range(6):
    plt.plot(x_data, y_data[plot_num], label=label_list[plot_num])
```